# Reduce file size on upload

Tags: php, image, upload

I have this script for uploading a image to my website but i would like to reduce the file size before it uploads but not reduce the dimensions whats the best way of going about this? i would prefer to do it while uploading it rather than sorting it out after if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

```
if (isset($_POST['addphotogallery']))
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    }

    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "GIF", "JPEG", "JPG", "PNG");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") ||
         ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) &&
        ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000000) &&
         in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_exists("gallery/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "gallery/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Image Uploaded";
                $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery SET filename='".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."' , imagedesc='".$_POST['imgdesc']."' , imagename='".$_POST['imgname']."'";
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant change a file, until you have the file

Comment: Your code is just copy + pasted code you've found from the internet. Where are your attempts to resolve this problem?

Comment: i have tried to understand many ways of doing it i just cannot work it out i was wondering if anyone on here could do it

Comment: if `[error]` is non-zero, then you should abort processing entirely. that means the file FAILED to upload, and the rest of the processing is useless - you may not have a file to process AT ALL. You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but mysql is deprecated.  You should consider switching to mysqli or PDO